# Send integer value to server

Tags: vb.net, httpclient, vb.net-to-c#

I'm trying to upload an image to server through an api along with few parameters

- Id (Int)
- ImageExtension(String)
- Image (image-jpeg)

```
Dim s_URL As String = "here is my api"

Dim fromData = New MultipartFormDataContent()
fromData.Add(New StringContent(22089), "Id")
fromData.Add(New StringContent("jpeg"), "ImageExtension")


Dim imgPath = "location to pic"
Dim imgStream = New FileStream(imgPath , FileMode.Open)
Dim streamContent = New StreamContent(fileStream)
streamContent.Headers.ContentType = New System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg")

fromData.Add(streamContent, "image", Path.GetFileName(imgPath))



Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync(s_URL, fromData).Result

Dim contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

Now the issue is the server is expecting integer($int32) value Id but I couldn't find a means to send integer value to the server along with the rest of parameters. I am getting error message `Could not convert string to integer: IV\u0000\u0000. Path 'payload.Id`

how do I send integer value from client to server? the server is strictly accepts and expecting for integer value only.

Comment: Does that code compile with [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement)? I can't see an overload of the [StringContent Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent.-ctor) which takes an integer as its only parameter. Maybe you intended `New StringContent("22089")`.

Comment: I tried `New StringContent("22089")` but still the same error, which means the server is getting string value for the `Id` instead it should be `Int32`

Comment: Can you give us a link to the API documentation?